# Shell script while read loop executes only once

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am writing a shell script to batch process .mov files off my camera through [Handbrake](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide) to save HD space. The script searches a directory with 'find' and then runs Handbrake on each .mov file found, matching the creation date of the resulting file to the source file's date with 'touch'.

I originally did this with a **for** loop:

```
for i in $(find "$*" -iname '*.mov') ; do
  ~/Unix/HandbrakeCLI --input "$i" --output "$i".mp4 --preset="Normal"
  touch -r "$i" "$i".mp4
done
```

This worked, but failed if the input files had spaces in their file names. So I tried a **while** loop instead:

```
find "$*" -iname '*.mov' | while read i ; do
  ~/Unix/HandbrakeCLI --input "$i" --output "$i".mp4 --preset="Normal"
  touch -r "$i" "$i".mp4
done
```

The problem with this loop is that it works for the first file in the directory, and then exits the loop. Note that if I substitute an "echo $i" in the body of the while loop, it prints all of the .mov files in the directory, so the loop is structured correctly.

I believe there is a partial answer to my question on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627838/why-does-bash-loop-deploy-script-only-seem-to-work-once). But the solution is specific to ssh and doesn't solve the general problem. Seems to have something do do with stdin being used by a sub-process, but I don't exactly understand how this works.

Any advice?

I'm on OSX 10.6

Comment: `${SHELL}` == `'/bin/bash'`, one presumes?

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing what $* is supposed to be. Is it supposed to be a list of files or directories? Or the current directory? Looks very much like you just use the wrong `file` argument with the wrong shell special parameter (e.g. use `file "$@"` instead of `"$*"`).

Comment: `"$*"` is quite certainly wrong; you definitely want `"$@"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2708635/218418): I now echo nothing into HandbrakeCLI to ensure it's not using the same stdin as my script:

```
find . -name "*.mkv" | while read FILE
do
    echo "" | handbrake-touch "$FILE"

    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        echo "$FILE had problems" >> errors.log  
    fi
done
```

...and it works as intended/expected.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the [safe find](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    ~/Unix/HandbrakeCLI --input "$REPLY" --output "$REPLY".mp4 --preset="Normal"
    touch -r "$REPLY" "$REPLY".mp4
done 9< <( find "$@" -type f -print0 )
```

This should be POSIX compatible, but only works if neither `HandbrakeCLI` nor `touch` read from standard input *and* no file names contain newlines:

```
find "$@" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r
do
    ~/Unix/HandbrakeCLI --input "$REPLY" --output "$REPLY".mp4 --preset="Normal"
    touch -r "$REPLY" "$REPLY".mp4
done
```

Comment: I tried running this and got an error: "syntax error near unexpected token `<'    I should note that I don't understand what the first two lines mean, so I'm not able to fix it myself.

Comment: that means that you are probably not on bash. Please report output of 'echo $0' in the context of the script? Or, what version of bash is this (`bash --version`)

Comment: bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
echo $0: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/N/Unix/bin/nsqueezemovs

Comment: @beibei Does your script start with `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`? It needs to be the latter for `<()` to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running with a shellopt '-e' (exit on errors)

Try

```
set +e
```

Comment: Setting +e did not make any difference. Handbrake executes once on the first file in the while-read loop and then breaks out of the loop and executes the remainder of the script. I don't thing the problem has to do with errors, because handbrake completes successfully.

Comment: Could you try to do the Handbrake step in a subshell (`Handbrake`)

Comment: I tried running handbrake in a subshell, but it had no effect on the problem I'm having. I tried subshelling the entire loop, and also just the call to handbrake. Same result both ways.

Answer (score 1):

This link fixed the problem for me on Ubuntu Linux 11.04 .

[Preventing a child process (HandbrakeCLI) from causing the parent script to exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708097/preventing-a-child-process-handbrakecli-from-causing-the-parent-script-to-exit)

Here is the code that works for me:

```
ls -t *.mpeg | tail -n +2 | while read name
do echo "$name" ; in="$name" ; out=coded/"`echo $name | sed 's/.mpeg$/.mkv/'`"
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$in" -o "$out" -a '1,2' ; mv -v "$name" trash/"$name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem.  I think HandbrakeCLI is consuming stdin.  I don't have my actual system here, but my testing shows that's what is probably happening.

"output" is a file with the numbers 1-10, each on their own line.

```
while read line ; do echo "MAIN: $line"; ./consumer.sh; done < output
```

consumer.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line ; do
  echo "CONSUMER: $line"
done
```

Results:

```
MAIN: 1
CONSUMER: 2
CONSUMER: 3
CONSUMER: 4
CONSUMER: 5
CONSUMER: 6
CONSUMER: 7
CONSUMER: 8
CONSUMER: 9
CONSUMER: 10
```

Changing the outer while loop will fix the problem:

```
while read line ; do echo "MAIN: $line"; ./consumer.sh < /dev/null; done < output
```

Results:

```
MAIN: 1
MAIN: 2
MAIN: 3
MAIN: 4
MAIN: 5
MAIN: 6
MAIN: 7
MAIN: 8
MAIN: 9
MAIN: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider just using `find` to invoke a shell, instead of wrapping `find` in a `while` loop.

```
find "$@" -iname '*.mov' -exec sh -c '
    ~/Unix/HandbrakeCLI --input "$1" --output "$1".mp4 --preset="Normal"
    touch -r "$1" "$1".mp4
' _ {} ';'
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. Any chance you could elaborate on the meaning of the final line?

Comment: Sure!  It is, in a clean way, passing arguments to the inline script.  Consider `sh -c 'echo "$1"' _ "hello,world"`.  `sh` will run the basic, inline script `echo "$1"` passing as its arguments `_` and `hello,world`.
By convention, the 0th argument should hold the pathname to the command itself, which in this case doesn't make sense, so `_` is just a useless placeholder.  Hopefully that helps!