# Not every command is being for in a while loop

Tags: linux, bash, handbrake

I am trying to make a script what looks at a folder and will automatically encode files that go into that folder using hand brake. I want to do this doing monitoring the folder using inotify putting the new additions to the folder into a list then using a cron job to encode them overnight. However when using a while loop to loop over the list handbrake only encodes the first file exists then the scripts carrys on to after the loop without doing every file in the list. Here is the script that is calling handbrake:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$(basename "$line")"
    HandBrakeCLI -Z "Very Fast 1080p30" -i "$line" -o "$line.m4v"
    rm "$line"
done < list.txt

> list.txt
```

When testing the loop with a simple echo instead of the HandBrakeCLI it works fine and prints out every file so I have no idea what is wrong.

Here is the scripts that is monitoring the folder incase that is the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -f list.txt ]
then
    touch list.txt
fi

inotifywait -m -e create --format "%w%f" tv-shows | while read FILE
do
    echo "$FILE" >> list.txt
done
```

Any help would be great, thanks

EDIT:
Just to be more specific, the script works fine for the first file in the list.txt, it encodes it no problem and removes the old version, but then it doesn't do any of the others in the list

Comment: You can run the first script using `bash -xv YourHandbrakeScriptName` to see all variables as each line is executed.

Comment: apart from the output from handbrake which I can post if it is needed I just output this:
+ rm 'tv-shows/Marvels The Avengers- Trailer (OFFICIAL).mp4'
+ IFS=
+ read -r line

# > list.txt
I also commented out the >list.txt for testing so I can keep running the encoder on the list.txt without having to retype it

Not too sure what I am looking for. Just currently testing it with trailers

Comment: Mmm, you could try adding a space followed by `< /dev/null` to the end of the line starting `HandbrakeCLI` in case it's grabbing the `stdin`.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work, I tried HandBrakeCLI .... < /dev/null and HandBrakeCLI .... > /dev/null but still nope, it still only does the first file in the list, not all of them

Comment: Does it list all files if you comment out the `HandbrakeCLI` line?

Comment: Yeah so if I change the script and replace the HandBrakeCLI line with a echo $line then it prints out every line in the list.txt file fine

Comment: It looks like Handbrake does grab `stdin`... https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/1316 which means it could `eat` your other input files.

Comment: Echoing nothing into HB may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414265/2836621

Comment: Yeah it now works perfect, thank you very much

Comment: Cool! Maybe upvote linked answer from @gabkdlly Good luck with your project.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for `echo "" | ...` to work when `... < /dev/null` fails. Can you please double check?

Comment: Can do, the exact command I did was HandBrakeCLI -Z "Very Fast 1080p30" -i "$line" -o "$line.m4v" < /dev/null is that the correct way?

Comment: Yes, if that's all a single line, it should have the same effect

Comment: Okay sorry to @mark-setchell for wasting your time, I must have made a mistake when typing in < /dev/null or not saved the file because just re checked and doing that did solve the problem, not too sure where I went wrong. The < /dev/null is nw working so I'll use that instead thanks

Comment: For your convenience, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) also automatically suggests this

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that, I will keep that tool in mind for future problems. I am new bash and sh scripting in general at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414265/2836621)

To solve the problem simply

```
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI ......
```

or

```
HandBrakeCLI ...... < /dev/null
```